# GetAll - UnimplementedFeatureError: Nested dynamic arrays not implemented here

Tags: solidity

I am creating the following contract:

```
pragma solidity ^ 0.4.17;

contract TodoList {

    event NewTodo(uint todoId, string value);
    event DeleteTodo(uint todoId, string value);

    mapping(uint => address) public todoOwner;
    mapping(address => uint) ownerTodoCount;

    TodoItem[] public todoItems;

    struct TodoItem {
        string value;
        //TODO submit ether to a TodoItem
        bool active;
    }

    function createTodo(string _value) internal returns(uint) {
        uint id = todoItems.push(TodoItem(_value, true)) - 1;
        todoOwner[id] = msg.sender;
        ownerTodoCount[msg.sender]++;
        NewTodo(id, _value);
        return id;
    }

    function getAllTodos() constant returns(string[], bool[]) {
        uint length = todoItems.length;

        string[] memory values = new string[](length);
        bool[] memory actives = new bool[](length);

        for (uint i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            values[i] = todoItems[i].value;
            actives[i] = todoItems[i].active;
        }

        return (values, actives);
    }  
}
```

I would like to display all todos by a user. For this I created the `getAllTodos` function.

However, when doing `truffle compile` I get the following error:

> UnimplementedFeatureError: Nested dynamic arrays not implemented here.

Any suggestions how to access all todos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So dynamic nested arrays are something not perfectly handled by solidity as of now. Every time you access a function involving a nested array, it must be internal. Thus, I am guessing the error could be in `function getAllTodos` whose access scope isn't specified, thus defaulting to public.

I hope this works! (PS- I have heard that this could also fail because nested arrays isn't fully implemented yet, but well worth a try

Comment: Thx for your reply! Would you be so kind to add a sample code, how to do it better? I guess this might be highly relevant for future "answer" searchers.

Comment: So I think the code could work if you have the following function definition:
`function getAllTodos() internal returns(string[], bool[])`